# Moving text up on a page

Tags: html, css, text, bootstrap-5, whitespace

I have very little knowledge of CSS and bootstrap.  I have multiple divs on a page and trying to get them lined up based on our old website.

The issue I am having is one div is larger on the right and the div on the left has a ton of white space due to the one on the right: (see screen shot)

[image]

Here is my  UI code:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6 col-sm-6">
    <h5><b>PRODUCER MAILINGS AND IMPORTANT UPDATES</b></h5>
    <hr class="fa-border border-primary border-1" />
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
      <li onclick="location.href='mydoc'"><img border="0" src="../images/icons/pdf.jpg" />&nbsp;Name1</li>
      <li onclick="location.href='mydoc'"><img border="0" src="../images/icons/pdf.jpg" />&nbsp;name goes here</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 col-sm-6">
    <h3><b>XXXXXX Mitigation Credits</b></h3>
    <hr class="fa-border border-primary border-1" />
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
      <li onclick="location.href='mydoc'"><img border="0" src="../images/icons/pdf.jpg" />&nbsp;name goes here</li>
      <li onclick="location.href='mydoc'"><img border="0" src="../images/icons/pdf.jpg" />&nbsp;name goes here</li>
      <li onclick="location.href='mydoc'"><img border="0" src="../images/icons/pdf.jpg" />&nbsp;name goes here</li>
      <li onclick="location.href='mydoc'"><img border="0" src="../images/icons/pdf.jpg" />&nbsp;name goes here</li>
      <li onclick="location.href='mydoc'"><img border="0" src="../images/icons/pdf.jpg" />&nbsp;name goes here</li>
      <li onclick="location.href='mydoc'"><img border="0" src="../images/icons/pdf.jpg" />&nbsp;name goes here</li>
      <li onclick="location.href='mydoc'"><img border="0" src="../images/icons/pdf.jpg" />&nbsp;name goes here</li>
      <li onclick="location.href='mydoc'"><img border="0" src="../images/icons/pdf.jpg" />&nbsp;name goes here</li>
      <li onclick="location.href='mydoc'"><img border="0" src="../images/icons/pdf.jpg" />&nbsp;name goes herey</li>
      <li onclick="location.href='mydoc'"><img border="0" src="../images/icons/pdf.jpg" />&nbsp;name goes here</li>
      <li onclick="location.href='mydoc'"><img border="0" src="../images/icons/pdf.jpg" />&nbsp;name goes here</li>
      <li onclick="location.href='mydoc'"><img border="0" src="../images/icons/pdf.jpg" />&nbsp;name goes here</li>
      <li onclick="location.href='mydoc'"><img border="0" src="../images/icons/pdf.jpg" />&nbsp;name goes here</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="w-100"></div>
  <div class="col-6 col-sm-6" style="vertical-align:top">
    <h3><b>OTHER MANUALS AND PROCEDURES</b></h3>
    <hr class="fa-border border-primary border-1" />
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
      <li onclick="location.href='mydoc'"><img border="0" src="../images/icons/pdf.jpg" />&nbsp;name goes here</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Tried moving things around and various CSS stuff from google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap's grid is based on rows and columns. Each row is composed of 12 columns, and your example shows one row, with two six-column wide divs. Then below that you have another six-column div. To get that lower div to be below the one you need, you want to move it into the column instead of it being below the row.

If you're going to continue to work with Bootstrap, I suggest you familiarize yourself with [how it works](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/layout/grid/).

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6 col-sm-6">
    <h5><b>PRODUCER MAILINGS AND IMPORTANT UPDATES</b></h5>
    <hr class="fa-border border-primary border-1" />
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
      <li onclick="location.href='mydoc'"><img border="0" src="../images/icons/pdf.jpg" />&nbsp;Name1</li>
      <li onclick="location.href='mydoc'"><img border="0" src="../images/icons/pdf.jpg" />&nbsp;name goes here</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12" style="vertical-align:top">
      <h3><b>OTHER MANUALS AND PROCEDURES</b></h3>
      <hr class="fa-border border-primary border-1" />
      <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li onclick="location.href='mydoc'"><img border="0" src="../images/icons/pdf.jpg" />&nbsp;name goes here</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 col-sm-6">
    <h3><b>XXXXXX Mitigation Credits</b></h3>
    <hr class="fa-border border-primary border-1" />
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
      <li onclick="location.href='mydoc'"><img border="0" src="../images/icons/pdf.jpg" />&nbsp;name goes here</li>
      <li onclick="location.href='mydoc'"><img border="0" src="../images/icons/pdf.jpg" />&nbsp;name goes here</li>
      <li onclick="location.href='mydoc'"><img border="0" src="../images/icons/pdf.jpg" />&nbsp;name goes here</li>
      <li onclick="location.href='mydoc'"><img border="0" src="../images/icons/pdf.jpg" />&nbsp;name goes here</li>
      <li onclick="location.href='mydoc'"><img border="0" src="../images/icons/pdf.jpg" />&nbsp;name goes here</li>
      <li onclick="location.href='mydoc'"><img border="0" src="../images/icons/pdf.jpg" />&nbsp;name goes here</li>
      <li onclick="location.href='mydoc'"><img border="0" src="../images/icons/pdf.jpg" />&nbsp;name goes here</li>
      <li onclick="location.href='mydoc'"><img border="0" src="../images/icons/pdf.jpg" />&nbsp;name goes here</li>
      <li onclick="location.href='mydoc'"><img border="0" src="../images/icons/pdf.jpg" />&nbsp;name goes herey</li>
      <li onclick="location.href='mydoc'"><img border="0" src="../images/icons/pdf.jpg" />&nbsp;name goes here</li>
      <li onclick="location.href='mydoc'"><img border="0" src="../images/icons/pdf.jpg" />&nbsp;name goes here</li>
      <li onclick="location.href='mydoc'"><img border="0" src="../images/icons/pdf.jpg" />&nbsp;name goes here</li>
      <li onclick="location.href='mydoc'"><img border="0" src="../images/icons/pdf.jpg" />&nbsp;name goes here</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! and thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @DotNetter if that solved your issue, you are supposed to accept the answer.